# Improper results from searching on a URL in solr

Tags: url, solr, nutch

I must be doing something wrong trying to run the following search

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=url:www.abc.com&wt=xml&indent=true
```

It is not giving this sites results back, it's giving everything back.  The schema.xml is pretty vanilla in how url is set up.

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField"
        positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1"
                catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"
                splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

<fieldType name="url" class="solr.TextField"
        positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

If I use host:www.abc.com, it works.

Why the seemingly incorrect results when using the url field?

Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to using KeywordTokenizerFactory, you will have to remove the WordDelimiterFilterFactory.  WDF splits tokens on punctuation and other delimiters ... which are very plentiful in URLs.  You'll have to rebuild your index after making the change and restarting Solr or reloading the core.

An alternate idea, if you don't need to force URLs to lowercase: Switch from TextField to StrField and get rid of the analyzer config entirely.

Comment: Thanks very much.  This does indeed work, if I rebuild my indexes.  I was hoping not to have to do that.  But you have answered my questions.  Both approaches work, I've tested both.  Thanks very much, again.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are on Solr 3.1 or greater.

StandardTokenizerFactory - It creates token based on [Word Boundary rules](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory). This means URLs will be broken into multiple tokens and match on any one of them would be considered a hit.

Try using [KeywordTokenizerFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory), for your `url` fieldtype. This should preserve the complete URL and match against it only.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I knew it had to be something like that.  That was the answer.

Comment: Whoops!  spoke to soon.  Nope, didn't work. It is still bringing back all the results.  Yes, am on 4.2.